# Cypher multi-tiered data request causes crash of client

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm having trouble with a query to extract a subset of the database.
The data is 7 tiers deep and when I try to extract the results through either my application or in the neo4j client it causes a crash.
The database isnt huge, total of 6556 nodes, and I've added with statements at each step to prevent creating a huge cartesian product. I'm guessing I've misunderstood what is happening with the data collection but when I run 'explain' on the query it maxes at  529 rows to begin with and quickly reduces.
Any advice on how I can improve this, or guidance on the correct approach would be greatly appreciated.

```
MATCH (g:G)
with g, { Name:g.Name, Id:g.Guid } as g_
MATCH (f)-[:HASG]->(g)
WITH f, { Name:f.Name, Id:f.Guid, Children:collect(distinct g_)} as f_
MATCH (e)-[HASF]->(f)
WITH e, { Name:e.Name, Id:e.Guid, Children:collect(distinct f_)} as e_
MATCH (d)-[:HASE]->(e)
WITH d, { Name:d.Name, Id:d.Guid, Children:collect(distinct e_)} as d_
MATCH (c)-[:HASD]->(d)
WITH c, { Name:c.Name, Id:c.Guid, Children:collect(distinct d_)} as c_
MATCH (b)-[:HASC]->(c)
WITH b, { Name:b.Name, Id:b.Guid, Children:collect(distinct c_)} as b_
MATCH (a)-[:HASB]->(b)
WITH { Name:a.Name, Id:a.Guid, Children:collect(distinct b_)} as a_
RETURN a_
```

Comment: is there any reason why do you have many relationship types as single relationship type works best in hiearchical tress. https://tbgraph.wordpress.com/2017/04/01/neo4j-location-trees is example. Also if you are returning only top 2 tiers of your trees, why do you iterate over all tiers ?

Comment: I think the fact that the Cypher query has so many layers means that you're thinking in imperative terms rather than in declarative terms about what you want to extract. Can you put together an example database and state in clear terms what you'd like the results to be? Then I think you'll get some help. It's not clear what data you want from the query above because it's too abstract.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this guys. Sorry the question isnt too clear, what I'm expecting to achieve here is to return the full matched dataset in a nested format where the returned a_ objects each have a collection of b_ which in turn have collections of c_ etc...

I'll put together a sample database and upload it shortly.

Thanks